# Using 'new Boolean()' to evaluate logical expressions

Tags: javascript

How can I evaluate (to true or false) a logical expression stored in a var as a string, *without* using eval()?:

```
var test = '(1 < 2 || 2 < 1) && 1 < 0)'
```

Comment: The `new Boolean` part of that is completely redundant, and in fact, actively counterproductive. `(1 < 2 || 2 < 1) && 1 > 0` is already all you need.

Comment: The actively counterproductive aspect is that it creates a Boolean wrapper object instead of an actual boolean, and the wrapper object is considered true if you try to use it in an `if` or otherwise treat it as a boolean, even if the wrapper is a wrapper around `false`.

Comment: OK. So, is there any way to achieve what I need, or is this evaluation ability a feature of console.log() ?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: `console.log` also has nothing to do with the evaluation. The evaluation is just how Javascript works. It evaluates expressions. The expression `(1 < 2 || 2 < 1) && 1 > 0` evaluates to `true`, and the expression `'(1 < 2 || 2 < 1) && 1 < 0)'` evaluates to a string.

Comment: Given a var holding a string with a logical expression (numbers, logical operators, and parenthesis), get the true or false value *without* using eval(). (We're not allowed to use eval()).

Comment: @bitsmcgee77 You are supposed to write a parser then

Comment: Isn't there a way to avoid writing a parser, given that JavaScript alone is able to evaluate the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var test = '((1 < 2 || 2 < 1) && 1 < 0)';
console.log(new Boolean(new Function(`return ${test}`)()));
```

Comment: You could also add a `.valueOf()` at the end to get the primitive value

Comment: Thanks for this. Question: is this as dangerous as eval()?

Comment: _"Question: is this as dangerous as eval()?"_ Not sure what you mean; what is the context?

Comment: `new Function` is very much similar to `eval`, in that it allows you to execute arbitrary pieces of code.

Comment: In the sense of being vulnerable to running injected code. That is what I understood the danger of eval() to be. Excuse my ignorance, I'm very new to JS.

Comment: Original Question does not query as to "dangerous", or "vulnerable" _"How can I evaluate (to true or false) a logical expression stored in a var as a string, without using eval()?"_

Comment: Yes, guest271314, I did mark your answer as correct. I was just curious.

Comment: @bitsmcgee77 Any number of processes could be considered "dangerous" or "vulnerable" without clear definition of "dangerous", "vulnerable", context, parameters and expected results.

Comment: @Kaiido, it was my fault- the first version of my question used new Boolean(), and for no good reason.

Comment: Possibly stacksnippets disallows it, along with eval() itself, due to the risk of executing arbitrary pieces of code?